# gdb takes too long and Ctrl-C has no effect

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I have major issue with GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (6.8.50.20090302-1.5.18).

It takes ages to print the value of a nested symbol and hitting Ctrl-C has no effect.
Do you know the reason? Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try GDB 7.2. There have been many fixes since 6.8, e.g.

```
2009-07-23  Paul Pluzhnikov  <ppluzhnikov@google.com>

        * symtab.c (search_symbols): Add QUIT.
```

The fix above should make Control-C work. Other fixes sped up searching for symbols, so you may not have a reason to hit Control-C in the first place :-)

Comment: At long last, I think I have found the true identity of Employed Russian :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it blocking on some network input, i.e. is it a library call waiting for the kernel to answer?

Have you tried debugging it from root? (careful here)

Can you set a watchpoint so that it will break before the culprit line?

Can you paste some code, too? :)

Comment: Hi lorenzog. I cannot post code here. I am assuming that the problem is on gdb,g++ or evern compile flags. I am facing the problem after the gdb upgrade.

Comment: Ok then it might be a gdb quirk. Quickest thing to do would be to try an older version and see what happens, then trying getting the latest patches from svn and compile your own. I also recommend reading the description of what changed in gdb lately.. worst case scenario you will end up learning something new.